# Why does the Practical Module & Constructor patterns accept this as a global?

Tags: javascript

The [Practical Module](https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js#practical) pattern accepts `this` as a global:

```
(function( global )
  var Module = ...
  ...
  ...

  global.Module = Module;
})( this );
```

What's the rational behind this decision?

The same goes for the Practical Constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you quote is technically equivalent to:

```
(function()
  var Module = ...
  ...
  ...

  this.Module = Module;
})();
```

and if it's used as intended, outside of a constructor or method, then `this` will refer to the global object (such as `window`). By using the name `global` instead of `this` to refer to it, the code makes it more explicit that this is what's happening. (You have to admit, "`global`" is a clearer name for the global object than "`this`"!)

Comment: That makes sense, naming & being explicit is important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm somehow missing your point.
This refers to the current scope / the current object. If you put this in your 'global' scope *this* will the window element (or whatever the global object is).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tmp = {
    someVar: null,
    init: function( someVar ){
        this.someVar = someVar;
    }
};

tmp.init( this );

window.console.log( tmp.someVar === window ); // true
</script>
```

now *tmp.someVar* and *window* is the same object

Comment: Are you missing the point of my question? I asked why a certain pattern was promoted on a certain website ... I'm not sure how your post is an answer to my question.